# SQL database design advice

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a `product` table:

```
ProdId(PK)
Prod1
Prod2
Prod3 
Prod4
```

and `Certification` table:

```
Certification(PK):
Cert1
Cert2
Cert3
```

How do I Model the following relation (pseudo table):

```
ProdwithCertId(PK)              ProdwithCert
ProdwithCert1                   "Prod1 with Cert1"
ProdwithCert2                   "Prod1 with Cert1, Cert2"
ProdwithCert3                   "Prod1 with Cert1, Cert2, Cert3"
ProdwithCert4                   "Prod2 with Cert1, Cert2"
ProdwithCert5                   "Prod2 with Cert1, Cert2, Cert3"
```

Cannot have duplicates, e.g. in above table, `ProdwithCert6 - "Prod2 with Cert1, Cert2, Cert3"` is not allowed

Comment: This question should be moved to dba.stackexchange.com since it seems to be db schema related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the schema.

```
table product (id, name)
table certification (id, name)
table product_group (id, product_id)
table product_group_certification (id, product_group_id, certification_id)
```

Now, let's assume we took the `Prod2` in your example above, in this schema it looks like this.

```
**product**
1, Prod2

**certification**
1, Cert1
2, Cert2
3, Cert3

**product_group**
1, 1  // Prod2 with Cert1, Cert2
2, 1  // Prod2 with Cert1, Cert2, Cert3

**product_group_certification**
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 2, 1
4, 2, 2
5, 2, 3
```

Comment: MIke, the Schema does not prevent duplicates in(product_group_certification). Do I have to implement a Trigger on "product_group_certification" to prevent duplicates?

Comment: @mxasim - that would be correct. There is no good way to provide what you're looking for regarding duplicates unless you flatten the database out into one table - but I know that's not what you're looking for. So, you'll need to query the table on INSERT and stop the INSERT if appropriate.

Comment: Mike, Thanks a lot on clarifying it

Comment: @mxasim - not a problem!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "psuedotable" above, are you meaning that the described table is only illustrative, or are you literally meaning you must store the text strings "Prod1 with Cert1", "Prod1 with Cert1, Cert2" and so on? If its the former, it would seem the basic solution to me would resemble the following:

```
ProdWithCertId (PK)    Prod (SK) Cert (SK)
1                      Prod1     Cert1
2                      Prod1     Cert2
3                      Prod1     Cert3
4                      Prod2     Cert1
5                      Prod2     Cert2
6                      Prod2     Cert3
```

Comment: psuedotable is only for illustration. Thanks,